# Smooth covering maps and the fundamental group

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, automorphism-group

Let $M$ be a smooth, connected and locally path-connected manifold, and let $\pi: \tilde{M}\to M$ be its universal cover. Let $\text{Aut}_\pi(\tilde{M})$ be the group of **smooth** covering transformations. We know that in the continuous case, the group of (not necessarily smooth) covering transformations of the universal cover is isomorphic to the fundamental group $\pi_1(M, q)$ (see for example [LeeTM, Cor. 11.32]).

However, I do not understand whether we still have such a group isomorphism when restricting ourselves to smooth covering transformations. So my question is: *What is the relationship between the fundamental group of a smooth manifold and the group of smooth covering transformations on its universal cover?*

[LeeTM] John Lee. Introduction to Topological Manifolds. (2000) Springer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $M$ is a manifold and $\hat M$ its universal cover, $\hat M$ is endowed with a differentiable structure such that $p:\hat M\rightarrow M$ is differentiable. For every $x\in M$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ is a domain chart $\phi:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and $p^{-1}(U)=\bigcup V_i$ and $p_{\mid V_i}\rightarrow U$ is an homeomorphism, the differentiable structure is defined by supposing that $p_i$ is a diffeomorphism which induces the chart $\phi\circ p_i$ on $\hat V_i$.

Now look at the action of an element $\gamma\in\pi_1(M)$ on $\hat M$, i.e. a covering transformation. We will prove that this action is already smooth. Let $p(y)=x$. There exist $i$ and $j$ such that $y\in V_i$ and $\gamma . y\in V_j$,
However, the map $(\phi\circ p_j) \circ \gamma \circ (\phi\circ p_i)^{-1}$ is the identity, this implies that action of $\gamma$ is differentiable.

This proves that every covering transformation is smooth.